# response payment system from bank after customer pay

Tags: php, json, curl

I expect I get some response after customer processs payment , then bank send call back to me so I create url to receive response from banking system for testing but it show nothing , so I try to post by myself(code at the end of post) to this url for testing but it also so show nothing

```
<?php

$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print $obj->{'partnerTxnUid'}; 
print $obj->{'partnerId'}; 

?>
```

This is the file that I sent data to above code

```
<?php
session_start();  
$accesstoken = $_SESSION['accesstoken'] ;

/* echo $accesstoken ;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($accesstoken); */

$mtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  


$certFile = "/etc/apache2/ssl/theamui/amui_com.crt";
$keyFile = "/etc/apache2/ssl/theamui/amui.com.key";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://theamui.com/payb/callback.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"partnerTxnUid\":\"RGH0 $mtime\",\n  \"partnerId\":\"CRP0000364\",\n  \"partnerSecret\":\"76W46SLUu0TStR2QFlm3wl4AyWVNajkU3aHNpRcfwZ27JyfDiz6I6TWstVNVqWuE\",\n  \"requestDt\":\"2021-12-28T20:12:28+07:00\",\n  \"merchantId\":\"KB000000518469\",\n  \"qrType\":\"3\",\n  \"txnAmount\":100.50,\n  \"txnCurrencyCode\":\"THB\",\n  \"reference1\":\"INV001\",\n  \"reference2\":\"ref2\",\n  \"reference3\":\"ref3\",\n  \"reference4\":\"ref4\",\n  \"metadata\":\"ถุงผ้า 80.50,ดินสอ 20.00\"\n}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $accesstoken";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $response;

$qrcodeinfo=json_decode($response)->{'qrCode'};
//var_dump($qrcodeinfo);
$_SESSION['qrcodeinfo'] = $qrcodeinfo;


/* $result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} */
// curl_close($ch);

// header( "refresh:0.1;url= ./qrcode/qrcode.php" );
?>
```

when I go to 'https://theamui.com/payb/callback.php' use Chrome browser it show

This page isn’t workingthekohsamui.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Are you intending to double-decode the input? You call `json_decode` twice

Comment: Ichange to <?php
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
// $obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->{'partnerTxnUid'}; 
print $obj->{'partnerId'}; 
?>    but it the same result   I will edit code in question

Comment: Decoding the response from your `callback.php` as JSON makes no sense because it doesn't return JSON - it simply prints two values as plain text. Also, if all you see is a 500 error, then please check the php error log on your server to find out the underlying, specific error message